# 'No module named 'engine' error in Pytorch tutorial

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am following a [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html) on the PyTorch website and I can't figure out what package this import uses:

```
from engine import train_one_epoch, evaluate
```

I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\tv-training-code.py", line 13, in <module>
    from engine import train_one_epoch, evaluate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'engine'
```

For reference, I am using Conda to run the program and I have the latest PyTorch version installed. Any ideas for what package I need to install to make this work?

Comment: How have you installed the `engine` package?

Comment: @Ivan they have not - it is an omission in the tutorial, see answer below

Comment: Please give feedback to the author of that tutorial, so that they can fix it!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it is an issue known in their forum since Oct 19 (!), plus the solution is there in the accompanying colab notebook; not sure what more can (or should) I do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an obvious omission to the subject tutorial, which has caused justified confusion to others, too; this question has been raised in the [Pytorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-engine/59564) as well - here is the accepted answer:

> In `references/detection/`, we have a number of helper functions to simplify training and evaluating detection models. Here, we will use `references/detection/engine.py`, `references/detection/utils.py` and `references/detection/transforms.py`. Just copy them to your folder and use them here.

Essentially, the necessary steps are shown in the [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/tutorials/blob/gh-pages/_downloads/torchvision_finetuning_instance_segmentation.ipynb#scrollTo=-WXLwePV5ieP) accompanying the tutorial:

```
%%shell

# Download TorchVision repo to use some files from
# references/detection
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/vision.git
cd vision
git checkout v0.8.2

cp references/detection/utils.py ../
cp references/detection/transforms.py ../
cp references/detection/coco_eval.py ../
cp references/detection/engine.py ../
cp references/detection/coco_utils.py ../
```

which must be executed before you attempt to import anything from the `engine` module.

Comment: I had a similar error, that'll teach me to trust tutorials too much.

Comment: Same directory of py script that requires the import? In Windows the import is accepted when i locate the file but crashes when executing the script because 'No module named 'engine''